# Is it possible to work in multithread while processing images with Pypylon and Yolo?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, yolo

When I put the image I grab from Pypylon into the model, it takes 60 - 70 ms to return the result. But I'm generating 50 fps. I used a queue structure to get all frames into the model without missing frames. I'm writing on one side and reading on the other side, but no matter how many threads I create, the queue and memory are constantly swelling. Also when I increase the number of cameras it slows down much more. I am open to any suggestions for solving this kind of problem. Thank you.

I use lock and unlock operation before queue access between reader and writer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the image capture happening in a separate thread or a separate process? you have listed both in the tags... A `multiprocessing.Queue` has quite a bit of overhead to transfer large amounts of data. If your processing alone is slower than 50fps however, you simply need to make that faster or drop image frames in order to not get behind.

Comment: Just seperate threading. I have three queue per each camera. And a raeder for a queue.

Comment: idk much about yolo, but unless it releases the GIL substantially, separate reader threads won't net you more performance over single core. This is why I bring up multiprocessing, because it is often necessary to take advantage of multiple cores. The downside is that transferring data between processes is more complicated than between threads.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take a look GIL how is work. I didnt know that its run like this. I solved this problem by using GPU in YOLO. But if i need multi tasking like in this situation at the future, i will try multiprocessing. I know more complicated data sharing. Maybe i use sockets or something like that. Do you have any suggestions to me for data sharing in multiproceesing.